# how to set up MS Advertisement SDK with a windows store app developed in C++/CX

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, c++-cx

I added the Advertisement SDK reference, added an AdControl xaml control to my main page and compiled the project which threw no errors.However, on running the app a get a ComException (WinRT information: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type  AppName.Common.RelayCommand' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutra)

Is there any guide on how to set up Advertisement SDK with C++/CX Windows Store App.

Comment: which version of VS and Ad SDK are you using? Are you building a Win8 or a Win8.1 app?

Comment: a Win8.1 app..i am not sure if Ad SDK for Windows 8.1 is supported for C++/Cx Windows Store App

Comment: I just tried with a Blank XAML C++/CX app in VS2013 and added an adcontrol. It works fine for me.

Comment: it compiles fine for me but throws a runtime exception when executed.

Comment: It ran fine for me.  It loaded and displayed an ad in the control.